# Need a report to filter office hours

Tags: reporting

I need the report to show times that cases were opened so I can filter out the "out of office" times. I have already reduced the report to show no weekends and only weekdays but now need it to be more specific on actual office hours. This is very new to me but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a formula field that returns a checkbox labelled 'After hours?', with the following formula:

```
IF( 
OR( 
VALUE( MID( TEXT( CreatedDate ), 12, 2 ) )-4 > 17, 
VALUE( MID( TEXT( CreatedDate ), 12, 2 ) )-4 < 8) ,true,false )
```

This pulls the time from the created timestamp. -4 adjusts for the value being in GMT; we're in eastern. So this value is true if the record was created outside of 8-5. Added the filter 'After Hours?' EQUALS false to our reports.

Comment: Hi Ian, firstly thank you for the quick response. As I said I am massively new to this could you explain a bit further please or show and example?

Comment: First off, you will need admin privileges for this workaround.

Go to Setup -> Customize -> Cases -> Fields

Create New Custom Field of type 'Formula' with a return data type of 'Checkbox.' The formula is shown above. The values you will adjust are -4 (in two places), 17, and 8. -4 is the difference between EST and GMT. Use -5 for Central, -6 for Mountain, etc. 8 is for 8 am and 17 is 5 pm. Adjust these values for your office hours. Choose the visibility settings for the field as desired.

Comment: Each case create will have a check box marked TRUE if create outside of your business hours. So by setting a filter for 'After Hours?' EQUALS false, we display only cases created within business hours.